# Program that multiplies numbers over and over

Tags: python

Would appreciate a review on this. The program does work as it is intended to. However I am unsure if there is a more elegant or better way to execute this process with less code.

```
def main():

    print ('This program takes two numbers and multiplies them.') 
    print ('the result is multiplied by a third number') 
    print ('entered by the user too') 

    procedure()

def procedure():

    n = float(input('Enter a number: '))
    n2 = float (input('Enter a number: '))        
    value = n * n2
    y = value
    print value

    n3 = float(input('Multiply by: '))

    while n3 != '0':

        op = n3 * y  
        y = op        
        print y

        n3 = float(input('Multiply by: '))

main()
```

Answer (score 6):

Your program makes inconsistent use of Python 2 and 3. For 3.x you need `print('Hello World!')`, for 2.x you need `print 'Hello World!'`. I'm guessing that you are using 2x because you say your program works and `print value` (as above) only works in 2.x. Note that in 2.x, `input(prompt)` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`. In 3.x, `input()` now means `raw_input()` and `raw_input()` has been removed. Given 2.x, your code already `eval()`s input, no you don't need `float()`. However, `float(raw_input())` is safer so I'll use that below. Also, the use of `n3 != '0'` never works because `n3` is a `float` not a `string`. Finally, I've cleaned up the variable names and removed unnecessary assignments.

```
number1 = float(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
number2 = float(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
result = number1 * number2

print(result)

number3 = float(raw_input('Multiply by: '))

while not number3 == 0:
    result2 = number3 * result
    print result2

    number3 = float(raw_input('Multiply by: '))
```

Answer (score 4):

### Infinite loop

Your program is an infinite loop, since a float will never equal a string.

Since you claim that this program works as intended, I'll take you at your word, and say that the loop should be written using `while True: …`.

### Variables and functions

There are just too many variables being used for no good reason.  In particular `y` and `value` are redundant.

The variable names aren't meaningful, and neither is your function name.

It is customary to introduce your main code with the boilerplate [`if __name__ == '__main__': …`](//stackoverflow.com/q/419163/1157100).

### Input / output

You do `float(input(…))` multiple times.  It would be worthwhile to extract that into a function.

To print a multi-line string, write a [`"""multiline string"""`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).  In this case, the string can do double duty as your program's docstring, so that's how I would write it.

### Suggested implementation

```
"""This program takes two numbers and multiplies them.
the result is multiplied by a third number
entered by the user too"""

def prompt_float(prompt):
    return float(input(prompt))

def repeated_multiply():
    product = prompt_float('Enter a number: ') * \
              prompt_float('Enter a number: ')
    while True:
        print(product)
        product *= prompt_float('Multiply by: ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__doc__)
    repeated_multiply()
```

Comment: See the bit in my answer about Python 2/3. The OP is using Python 2, hence `input()` already `eval`s. In 2.x, `float(input(prompt))` is equivalent to `float(eval(input(prompt)))` in 3.x.

Comment: @BardiHarborow I saw your preexisting answer, and decided not to make an issue of the Python 2/3 distinction so that I could focus on other issues. Instead, I just suggested a solution that could work in both versions.

Comment: That's fine, I'm just being pedantic. =)

Answer (score 1):

Variable name:

- Have  a meaningful name for the variables and not `n`, `n3`, etc. Instead `product` , `multiplier`, etc would be good.

Others:

- using single print instead of multiple. A linebreak('\n') would be useful.
- What if `y = 0` from `n * n2`, then its a futile multiplication loop.
- Multiple variables for the same purpose: `value`, `y`, `op`.